# Display border if image available otherwise dont display border

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hei , 
Following is my html code and css  . I dont want to display border on picture if user has not uploaded picture in article. Now my code is not hard coded in html file and thats why image tag is also displaying for every short article .If some articles have not picture  border is still showing because i have style for it.
I dont want to display border if user has not uploaded any picture. How can i achieve this using jquery .Any idea.

```
<div class="ShortAticle">
    <div class="ShortArticlePicture">
        <a href="#"> <img alt="Title" src="/images/viewimage.aspx?id=ArticlePicture" /></a>
    </div>
    <div class="ArticleText">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.ShortArticlePicture img {
    border: 1px solid #cccc;
}
```

Comment: It would be preferable to do this with server side templating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following style, it will show border only if `src` attribute is present

```
.ShortArticlePicture img[src] {
    border: 1px solid #cccc;
}
```

Comment: you can even check to see if `img[src='']` if you are setting the src to an empty string. The style could then set display:none to hide the image tag. http://jsfiddle.net/xdjah/2/

Comment: but in my case i have src comes always <img src="/images/viewimage.aspx?id=" alt="2009"> but if user has not uploaded picture then in source id dont come and it dont display picture but its still showing border  . soo how to do in this case

Comment: you can check for `img[src='/images/viewimage.aspx?id=']` directly in css selector

Answer (score 1):

You have to use JavaScript for this purpose. One of the methods is shown below:

```
$(window).load(function(){ //Run on load
    $('img').each(function(){ //Loop through each image
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.height() == 0 || $this.width() == 0){ //If the image has no size
            $this.css('border', 'none'); // Example: Setting border to none
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative method would consist of adding a specific `class` to the article's images which have an image, and specify the `border` property for that class.

Depending on the case, I would recommend using a fixed size for your images, so that users won't be confused by an inconsistent lay-out.

Comment: The problem here will be that you have to put this code in the load and not in the ready event. Otherwise the images won't be loaded and you can not find the dimensions. BUT by executing this at onload you will see the border for a short time, until the script has executed.

Comment: What if the user defines a width and height in the markup? Is it looking at the actual dimensions of the image, or just the dimensions of the tag?

Comment: @JamesJohnson The calculated ("real") size will be used.